# Spring - Query parameters without question mark

Tags: spring, rest

I'm having an issue parsing an URL with Spring.
My endpoint is

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userActivation(@RequestParam("token") String token, @RequestParam("code") String code, final Map<String, Object> model) {
   ...
}
```

So I am expecting a `token` and a `code` in the URL.

The problem I am facing is that the service redirecting to my page omits the question mark, something like:

```
http://myapp/register/&token=sdgddfs&code=fdasgas
```

Which Spring fails to match to my endpoint.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: what is this service that's redirecting to your page? Seems like the issue is there tbh

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way to change the redirection URL from that service. The owner insists the request is legit.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write you method using @PathVariable instead of @RequestParam
So you'll have an URL like http://myapp/register/sdgddfs/fdasgas, and an annotation for method

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/register/{token}/{code}")
public String userActivation(@PathVariable("token") String token, @PathVariable("code") String code) { ... }
```

Comment: That would not work with the current redirection URL since there is no '/' after token. I would get a single variable containing "&token=...&code=..." which I would have to parse